# How to rotate just bottom half of model? With shapekeys?

Tags: animation, shape-keys, vertex-groups

Ok Ive made a paceman ghost and am trying to do what they did in Wreck it Ralph, with bottom half circling while top stays still:https://youtu.be/HgoUIvnDLGc

I think I need shapekeys, but if I just rotate bottom half I get:

[image]

Separating the bottom half due to the transparent material gets:

[image]

Is this possible?